# Django REST Framework and HTML pages

Tags: python, html, json, django, rest

I'm working on a project that uses Django on the server side and I have a REST(ish) API going.

One thing I'm wondering about. Is it considered ok practice to deliver Django HTML templates via the API endpoints? For example, by going to www.rooturl.com, an API endpoint is called and the HTML delivered. Then, when user clicks on, say FAQ, a GET request is made to www.rooturl.com/faq and an HTML template delivered again? Or should the FAQ items be delivered as JSON? Or maybe give both alternatives through content negotiation? At which point is all the HTML content usually delivered?

I couldn't find a satisfying answer with my google-fu.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of using Django HTML Templates in your API endpoint since the whole point of using a REST API is to have the server side and the client side completely independent from one another. So yes, the FAQ items should be delivered as JSON and displayed as you want on the client side.

Comment: So... you're implying I should ditch the T part of the Django's MTV architecture altogether? 


But isn't it also in the nature of a RESTful API to be able to get different types of data through a single endpoint? I could provide the front page in HTML, which will likely be quite static, for now and if need be in the future, also provide just the necessary data to build it in JSON format?


Asking questions because of inexperience with web programming.